# Readline application name

Tags: bash, readline

The Readline manual describes the available conditional constructs [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Init-Constructs.html#Conditional-Init-Constructs). In particular, the manual says

> The application construct is used to include application-specific settings. Each program using the Readline library sets the application name, and you can test for a particular value. This could be used to bind key sequences to functions useful for a specific program. For instance, the following command adds a key sequence that quotes the current or previous word in Bash:
>
> `$if Bash`
>
> `# Quote the current or previous word "\C-xq": "\eb\"\ef\""`
>
> `$endif`

Given an application using the readline library, how do you find out the value that it is setting for "application name"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to read the documentation for the application, which would undoubtedly tell you in the section about `readline`. (Yes, that was a joke.)

Here's one technique which might work:

A transcript with an application with debugging symbols:

```
$ gdb the_application
...
Reading symbols from /usr/local/bin/the_application...done.
(gdb) b rl_initialize
Breakpoint 1 at 0x496180: file readline.c, line 1050.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/the_application 

Breakpoint 1, rl_initialize () at readline.c:1050
1050    {
(gdb) p rl_readline_name
$1 = 0x4d1fbb "TheApplication"
```

A more likely transcript with an application without debugging symbols:

```
$ gdb the_application
...
Reading symbols from /bin/bash...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) break rl_initialize
Breakpoint 1 at 0x48df40
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/local/the_application

Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000048df40 in rl_initialize ()
(gdb) p (char*)rl_readline_name
$1 = 0x4b0bcb "TheApplication"
```

Comment: I get `error: Cannot access memory at address` when trying to print the name. 

Adding an println inside a basic rl application yields "other". Not very discriminating..

Comment: @olejorgenb: if you are writing an rl application, it is your responsibility to set the application name; if you don't do so, the readlune library won't do it for you. If you want other people to use your application, you should document what you set the name to. (The fact that hardly anyone can bw bothered to do this was the basis for the joke at the beginning of the answer.)

Comment: yup, figured it out even though it isn't particularly clear from the documentation. (It isn't my rl application though, but I included the change in my patch)

Comment: @olejorgenb: I received the same `error: Cannot access memory at address` error when testing against bash. I decided that I needed some `gdb` practice, so I spent some time trying to figure out. I was using bash and decided to build it myself which has the debug symbols. @rici's instructions worked like a charm. Then, I went back to the distro bash.

`info address rl_readline_name` gave me the address of `rl_readline_name`. Then `x/a 0x1000bff38` gave me the address to where it pointed to. And, finally `x/s 0x10009f18b` gave me the correct answer; "Bash".